# MongoDb Authentication for inMemoryDB?

Tags: mongodb, authentication

Does MongoDB in-memory Db support authentication?

I am using auth on mongo instances. Created admin user for both `wiredTiger` and `in-memory DB`.
While connecting with `wiredTiger` it gets connected but not with the `in-memory DB`.

Comment: The [page on in-memory storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/) says this: "Non-persisted data includes application data and system data, such as users, permissions, ...". So yes, looks like authentication/authorization should work there too.

Comment: but when i follow these steps given on mongo doc https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/ and restart after creating a user then the user no longer exist there.

Comment: What user, from the `admin` db? Can't be. But user for your in-memory database is gone, of course. You have to recreate it during setup of that db.

Comment: So, I have to create a user every time i start the in-memory database? Also how can i create user while starting in auth enabled mode as i am unable to connect to the imdb at that time.?

Answer (score 0):

#### This is what worked for me:

- `"mongodb-memory-server": "^8.9.0",`
- `"jest": "^27.2.5",`
- `"@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.0.3",`

```
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';
let mongo: MongoMemoryServer;
//..

mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create({
// Not recommended as every instance will spawn on a random port.
  // instance: { port: 27017 }, 
  binary: { version: '4.0.28' },
  auth: {
    // Add the root user
    customRootName: 'root-username',
    customRootPwd: 'root-password',
    // Add additional users
    extraUsers: [
      {
        createUser: 'other-username',
        pwd: 'other-password',
        roles: [
          { role: 'readWrite', db: 'db-name' },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
// Get the URI including random port
const mongoUri = await mongo.getUri();
//.. connect
```

When you connect make sure you that you specify the authentication credentials including the:

- `username`, `password`, `database` (db-name granted readWrite to)

#### Useful Jest Options

```
"test": "jest --maxWorkers=4 --force-exit --detectOpenHandles",
"test:mongo:debug": "MONGOMS_DEBUG=1 jest --maxWorkers=4 --force-exit --detectOpenHandles",
```

- `MONGOMS_DEBUG=1` enable debug mode for the in memory db. Very useful to figure out what is going on.
- `--force-exit` last resort for terminating the process after tests are run but consider `mongoose.disconnect()` and `await mongo.stop();` isntead.

#### Helpful References:

- https://dev.to/webeleon/unit-testing-nestjs-with-mongo-in-memory-54gd

#### Docker for Integration Tests

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
db-mongo-service-test:
  image: mongo:4.0.28                           # Build from MongoDB image
  container_name: db-mongo-test                 # Name the container
  environment:
    MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: db-name              # Set Database Name
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root-username   # Set root username
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root-password" # Set root user password
  volumes:                                      # Add a non-root user via init script.
    - ./server/scripts/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
  ports:
    - 27020:27020
    - 27017:27017
```